# HtmlWeb.cs not found HtmlAgilityPack in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-agility-pack

consider the following codes below,

```
public void HTMLText(string url)
{
    var web = new HtmlWeb(); //giving error that HtmlWeb.cs not found
    var doc = web.load(url);
}
```

I am getting error for HtmlWeb() that HtmlWeb.cs is not found in my project. What could I do to solve this error?